# SQL query according to submit form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to query the database according to the input of the amount deposited. In the database the bank minimal amounts are stored. So the query consists in showing all banks with min_amount

The amount is defined $amount, and the row containing the minimum amounts is minimum. So i have done it like this but it tells me: Undefined index for $amount. ???

```
 <form name="test" method="get" action="this.php">
    Amount: <input name="amount"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <?php
        $amount = $_GET["amount"];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list1 WHERE minimum <= '$amount'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo $row['bank_name'] . " - " . $row['Tariff'];
          echo "<br />";
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check if the form has been submitted with say isset function.

```
if (isset($_GET['amount'])){}
```

Also it is highly advisable that you escape your $_GET variables before placing them into a mysql query as this kind of code allows for SQL injections.

The whole thing should like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['amount'])){

        $amount = $_GET["amount"];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list1 WHERE minimum <= '{$amount}'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo $row['bank_name'] . " - " . $row['Tariff'];
          echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still get an error in this statement: $amount = $_GET["amount"]

Comment: Still after you very BIG help, dreamweaver show the red ribbon (error bar). I have the code exactly as you typed it. Don't know where is the problem???

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and your code is open for `sql_injection`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the form has been submitted or not. Try:

```
if( isset($_GET['amount'])) { /* your code here */ }
```